# Python: get values from multiple td and th have no tags using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a page that looks like this.

```
<tr>
    <th class="fst" scope="col">time(*)</th>
    <th scope="col">field</th>
    <th scope="col">1 session</th>
    <th scope="col">2 session</th>
    <th scope="col">3 session</th>
    <th scope="col">4 session</th>
    <th scope="col">5 session</th>
    <th scope="col">6 session</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th class="num_area" rowspan="11" scope="row">77</th>
   <td class="txt_category">bus</td>
   <td>58456</td>                                                                   
   <td>62891</td>                                                                    
   <td>63076</td>                                                             
   <td>53282</td>                                                                 
   <td>54805</td>                                                             
   <td>55097</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="txt_category">taxi</td>
   <td>-</td>
   <td>-</td>
   <td>-</td>
   <td>62891</td>
   <td>-</td>
   <td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>                         
    <th class="fst" scope="col">time(*)</th>
    <th scope="col">field</th>
    <th scope="col">7 session</th>
    <th scope="col">8 session</th>
    <th scope="col">9 session</th>
    <th scope="col">10 session</th>
    <th scope="col">11 session</th>
    <th scope="col">12 session</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th class="num_area" rowspan="11" scope="row">100</th>
   <td class="txt_category">bus</td>
   <td>1342</td>                                                                   
   <td>138470</td>                                                                    
   <td>878840</td>                                                             
   <td>7653</td>                                                                 
   <td>4422</td>                                                             
   <td>87630</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, this site has one table and in it, there are many  without class or tag and have many  and . Since the value is different from sessions, I have to scrap data like session and value pair.
Also, field names are different(bus, taxi ..) I have to get those names too.
The ideal result would be like this.

```
 result=[
   {session=1, scope=77, fieldname=bus, count=58456}, 
   {session=1, scope=77, fieldname=taxi, count=0},
   {session=2, scope=77, fieldname=bus, count=62891},
 ]
```

So What I've tried so far this like this.

```
def scraping():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    result = []
    for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
       header = row.findAll('th')
       if len(header) < 1:
           continue
       if len(header) == 7:
           for num in range(1, 7):
               date = header[num].find(text=True)

       if len(header) == 8:
           for num in range(1, 8):
               date = header[num].find(text=True)
       body = row.findAll('td')
       if len(body) < 1:
           continue
       field_name = body[0].find(text=True)
       template['field_name'] = field_name
       for num in range(1, 7):
           cost = body[num].find(text=True)
           template['cost'] = cost
       result.append(template)
```

sometimes  length is 7 and sometimes 8, so I decided to use range. However, after using it it seems like result list only has one dictionary which is not what I intended. I would like to know if there is good way to scrap those values.